# Inequality $\left ||x|^\sigma - |y|^{\sigma} \right | \leq C_{\alpha,\sigma,\lambda} |x|^{\sigma-\alpha} |x-y|^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inequality

Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and $\sigma \in \Bbb R$, $\lambda > 0$. Show that there exists a constant $C_{\alpha,\sigma,\lambda}>0$ such that the following holds:

For any $x,y \in \Bbb R^n \backslash \{0\}$ such that $|x-y| \leq \lambda \min\{|x|, |y|\}$ we have
$$ \left ||x|^\sigma - |y|^{\sigma} \right | \leq C_{\alpha,\sigma,\lambda } |x|^{\sigma-\alpha} |x-y|^\alpha$$
I am getting some hints but unable to prove them except the first one and then concluding the result:

1. Show that there exist $\Lambda > 0$ such that  $\Lambda^{-1} |x| \leq |y| \leq \Lambda |y|$
2. Then use a mean value theorem to show the inequality for $\alpha = 1$, $n \geq 2$.
3. You can deduce the case $\alpha \in [0,1]$ from the case $\alpha = 1$, and the case $n=1$ from the case $n=2$. Observe that $|x|^\sigma$ may not be differentiable in $x=0$!

The first can be done easily by chosing $\Lambda>\max\left\{\frac{|x|}{|y|},1\right\}$. For the mean value theorem on higher variables ${\displaystyle {\Bigg |}f(y)-f(x){\Bigg |}\leq {\Bigg |}\nabla f{\Big (}(1-c)x+cy{\Big )}{\Bigg |}\ {\Big |}y-x{\Big |}.}$ Now if we deal with $f(x)=|x|^{\sigma}$, we don't know whether it is differentiable or not!. Please help me here. I always find multivariable difficult.